# Determining Betweenness Centrality With The Igraph Library

Tags: python, igraph

I am a very, very mediocre programmer, but I still aim to use the [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) python library to determine the effect of a user's centrality in a given forum to predict his later contributions to that forum.

I got in touch with someone else who used the [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) library to do something similar, but given the current size of the forum, calculating exact centrality indices is virtually impossible--it just takes too much time.

This was his code though:

```
import networkx as netx
import sys, csv

if len(sys.argv) is not 2:
   print 'Please specify an input graph.'
   sys.exit(1)

ingraph = sys.argv[1]
graph = netx.readwrite.gpickle.read_gpickle(ingraph)

num_nodes = len(graph.nodes())
print '%s nodes found in input graph.' % num_nodes
print 'Recording data in centrality.csv'

# Calculate all of the betweenness measures
betweenness = netx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality(graph)
print 'Betweenness computations complete.'
closeness = netx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality(graph)
print 'Closeness computations complete.'

outcsv = csv.writer(open('centrality.csv', 'wb'))

for node in graph.nodes():
   outcsv.writerow([node, betweenness[node], closeness[node]])

print 'Complete!'
```

I tried to write something similar with the igraph library (which allows to make quick estimates rather than exact calculations), but I cannot seem to write data to a CSV file.

My code:

```
import igraph
import sys, csv

from igraph import *

graph = Graph.Read_Pajek("C:\karate.net")

print igraph.summary(graph)

estimate = graph.betweenness(vertices=None, directed=True, cutoff=2)
print 'Betweenness computation complete.'

outcsv = csv.writer(open('estimate.csv', 'wb'))

for v in graph.vs():
   outcsv.writerow([v, estimate[vs]])

print 'Complete!'
```

I can't find how to call individual vertices (or nodes, in NetworkX jargon) in the igraph documentation, so that's where I am getting error messages). Perhaps I am forgetting something else as well; I am probably too bad a programmer to notice :P

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe that's how to call individual vertices in igraph, @danihp!

Comment: ``vs`` is an attribute of the graph object that behaves like a list of vertices, so it is incorrect to use it as an index for ``estimate`` (since ``vs`` on its own is an undefined variable). You should use ``v.index`` in place of ``vs``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, individual vertices in igraph are accessed using the `vs` attribute of your graph object. `vs` behaves like a list, so iterating over it will yield the vertices of the graph. Each vertex is represented by an instance of the `Vertex` class, and the *index* of the vertex is given by its `index` attribute. (Note that igraph uses continuous numeric indices for both the vertices and the edges, so that's why you need the `index` attribute and cannot use your original vertex names directly).

I presume that what you need is the *name* of the vertex that was stored originally in your input file. Names are stored in the `name` or `id` vertex attribute (depending on your input format), so what you need is probably this:

```
for v in graph.vs:
    outcsv.writerow([v["name"], estimate[v.index]])
```

Note that vertex attributes are accessed by indexing the vertex object as if it was a dictionary. An alternative is to use the `vs` object directly as a dictionary; this will give you a list containing the values of the given vertex attribute for all vertices. E.g.:

```
from itertools import izip

for name, est in izip(graph.vs["name"], estimate):
    outcsv.writerow([name, est])
```

An even faster version using generator expressions:

```
outcsv.writerows(izip(graph.vs["name"], estimate))
```

Comment: You should decide whether you use ``import igraph`` (in which case you must construct your graph with ``igraph.Graph.Read_Pajek``) or ``from igraph import *`` (in which case you only need ``summary(graph)``). Also, you don't need ``import itertools``, only ``from itertools import izip``. Otherwise it seems fine for me.

Comment: So, am I correct to understand the complete code becomes:

(...)  
`graph = Graph.Read_Pajek("C:\karate.net")
print igraph.summary(graph)
estimate = graph.betweenness(vertices=None, directed=True, cutoff=2)  
print 'Betweenness computation complete.'
outcsv = csv.writer(open('estimate.csv', 'wb'))
outcsv.writerows(izip(graph.vs["name"], estimate))
print 'Complete!'`
Im sorry, I can't seem to get line breaks in comments. Anyway, @tamas, the above code results in a "KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist'" in `outcsv.writerows(izip(graph(vs["name"], estimate))`.  

Any idea?

Comment: Try with ``"id"`` instead of ``"name"``, or list the vertex attributes with ``print graph.vertex_attributes()`` to figure out which attribute holds the vertex names you need.

Comment: Using `"id"` instead of name yielded the same error; printing `graph.vertex_attributes()` returned just `[]`. I'm sorry if I come accross rather stupid--I'm fairly new to this :P

Comment: It looks like your graph has no vertex attributes, in which case you can identify the vertices only by their numeric indices. So, just use ``outcsv.writerows(enumerate(estimate))``.

Comment: Taking in account your further comments on the igraph mailing list, @Tamas, I now get an error "izip argument #2 must support iteration".  
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So, for the sake of clarity, the following eventually proved to do the trick:

```
import igraph
import sys, csv

from igraph import *
from itertools import izip

graph = Graph.Read_GML("C:\stack.gml")

print igraph.summary(graph)

my_id_to_igraph_id = dict((v, k) for k, v in enumerate(graph.vs["id"]))

estimate = graph.betweenness(directed=True, cutoff=16)
print 'Betweenness computation complete.'

print graph.vertex_attributes()

outcsv = csv.writer(open('estimate17.csv', 'wb'))

outcsv.writerows(izip(graph.vs["id"], estimate))

print 'Complete!'
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I noticed u chose to use cutoff=16 in this example,  I am wondering if there a rule of thumb when choosing the cutoff value? I am having 1.5 Million Vertices and 11 Million Edges, any suggestion on the cutoff value to choose?